# get OLE properties using IFilter C++

Tags: c++, com, ole, ifilter, windows-search

I've been using IFilter COM Object in order to extract text from files. 
I've managed to extract the OLE properties **values** (such as Author's Value, Company's Value etc.), but i could not figure out how to know which value is the Author, Company and so on..

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
IFilter *pFilt;
HRESULT hr = LoadIFilter( L"c:\\bla.docx", 0, (void**)&pFilt );
if ( FAILED( hr ) )
{
    cout<<"Bla"<<endl;
}

ULONG flags;
hr = pFilt->Init( IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_INDEX_ATTRIBUTES, 0, 0, &flags );
if ( FAILED( hr ) )
{
    cout<<"Bla"<<endl;
}
if(flags == 1)
{
    cout<<"With OLE!"<<endl;
}
STAT_CHUNK chunk;
while ( SUCCEEDED( hr = pFilt->GetChunk( &chunk ) ) )
{
    if ( CHUNK_TEXT == chunk.flags )
    {
        WCHAR awc[100];
        ULONG cwc = 100;
        while ( SUCCEEDED( hr = pFilt->GetText( &cwc, awc ) ) )
        {
            cout<<awc<<endl;
            // process the text buffer.&nbsp;.&nbsp;.
        }
    }
    else // CHUNK_VALUE
    {
        PROPVARIANT *pVar;
        while ( SUCCEEDED( hr = pFilt->GetValue( &pVar ) ) )
        {

            **// Right here, i can see the value of pVar is the correct author, but i dont know how to tell this is the author, or the company etc..**
            PropVariantClear( pVar );
            CoTaskMemFree( pVar );
        }
    }

}
```

In other words, i need to know what is the property id, and match it to the value of the propertie.

I've seen solutions using a IPropertyStorage->ReadMultiple but i'm trying to get the same using IFilter.

Thanks Alot! 
Hope you might find the answer.

Comment: The chunk's *attribute* member should interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is define in the `STAT_CHUNK's` `attribute` field. It's define as a `FULLPROPSPEC` structure, which can be (most of the time) directly related to [Windows Property System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728898(v=vs.85).aspx).

A FULLPROPSPEC can either point to a GUID+id property, or to a custom property defined by its name (ideally, you need to check for `psProperty.ulKind` to determine this). Today, most of implementation just don't use the name thing and stick to the GUID (property set) + PROPID (int) definition of a "property".

So for example, this is a sample code that is capable of determining what's the property name and value formatted as a string using [PSGetNameFromPropertyKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776502(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IPropertyDescription::FormatForDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761521(v=vs.85).aspx)  :

```
...
if (CHUNK_VALUE == chunk.flags)
{
  if (chunk.attribute.psProperty.ulKind == PRSPEC_PROPID)
  {
    // build a Windows Property System property key
    // need propsys.h & propsys.lib
    PROPERTYKEY pk;
    pk.fmtid = chunk.attribute.guidPropSet;
    pk.pid = chunk.attribute.psProperty.propid;
    PWSTR name;
    if (SUCCEEDED(PSGetNameFromPropertyKey(pk, &name)))
    {
      wprintf(L" name:'%s'\n", name);
      CoTaskMemFree(name);
    }

    IPropertyDescription *pd;
    if (SUCCEEDED(PSGetPropertyDescription(pk, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pd))))
    {
      PROPVARIANT *pVar;
      hr = pFilt->GetValue(&pVar);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
        LPWSTR display;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pd->FormatForDisplay(*pVar, PDFF_DEFAULT, &display)))
        {
          wprintf(L" value:'%s'\n", display);
          CoTaskMemFree(display);
        }
        PropVariantClear(pVar);
      }
      pd->Release();
    }

    continue;
  }  // otherwise it's a string

  PROPVARIANT *pVar;
  hr = pFilt->GetValue(&pVar);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
    // do something with the value
    PropVariantClear(pVar);
  }
}
```